# Implementing recursive grammars with Boost.Qi

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am using Boost.Spirit Qi to construct rather complex structure from  some text data. The data structure may be recursively defined, so I need two of my grammars to reference each other, and that is where problems emerge.

For example, I have a grammar:

```
element = line | text | circle | box | composite_element
composite_element = 'C', int, int, '[', +element, ']'
```

Obviously, I need something like that:

```cpp
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_eol.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

struct line {
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
    int color;
    int width;
    int capstyle;
    int dashstyle;
    int dashlength;
    int dashspace;
};

struct box {
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    int color;
    int line_width;
    int capstyle;
    int dashstyle;
    int dashlength;
    int dashspace;
    int filltype;
    int fillwidth;
    int angle1;
    int pitch1;
    int angle2;
    int pitch2;
};

struct circle {
    int x;
    int y;
    int radius;
    int color;
    int line_width;
    int capstyle;
    int dashstyle;
    int dashlength;
};

struct text {
    int x;
    int y;
    int color;
    int size;
    int visibility;
    int show_name_value;
    int angle;
    int alignment;
    int num_lines;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
};

struct composite_component;
using element_t = boost::variant<line, box, circle, text, boost::recursive_wrapper<composite_component>>;

struct composite_component {
    int x;
    int y;
    std::string basename;
    // only used if component is embedded
    // i. e. stores its definition within the schematic file
    std::vector<element_t> elements;
};

struct element {
    // some other fields
    // ...
    element_t element;
};

struct document {
    std::vector<element> elements;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(line, x1, y1, x2, y2, color, width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength, dashspace)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(box, x, y, width, height, color, line_width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength, dashspace, filltype, fillwidth, angle1, pitch1, angle2, pitch2)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(circle, x, y, radius, color, line_width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(text, x, y, color, size, visibility, show_name_value, angle, alignment, num_lines, lines)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(composite_component, x, y, basename, elements)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(element, element)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(document, elements)

template <typename Iterator, typename Attribute>
using rule = qi::rule<Iterator, Attribute, qi::blank_type>;

template <typename Iterator>
class composite_element_parser;

template <typename Iterator>
class element_parser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, element(), qi::blank_type> {
public:
    element_parser(): element_parser::base_type{start_rule_}
    {
        using qi::int_;
        using qi::repeat;
        using phoenix::val;
        using phoenix::construct;

        /* other definitions except of the 'line' is omitted in sake of simplicity */
        line_ = 'L' >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >>
                    int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> qi::eol;
        // box = ...
        // circle = ...
        // text = ...
        start_rule_ = (line_ /* || embedded_component_ */) >> qi::eoi;
    }
private:
    rule<Iterator, element()> start_rule_;
    rule<Iterator, line()> line_;
    // here comes the problem - CIRCULAR REFERENCE to incompletely defined template
    // composite_element_parser<Iterator> embedded_component_;
};

template <typename Iterator>
class composite_element_parser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, composite_component(), qi::blank_type> {
    public:
    composite_element_parser() : composite_element_parser::base_type{start_rule_}
    {
        using phoenix::at_c;
        using qi::int_;
        using phoenix::push_back;

        start_rule_ = "C" >> int_ >> int_ >>  qi::lexeme[(qi::char_)[at_c<2>(qi::_val) += qi::_1]]
                                                        >> -(
                                                           "[" >>
                                                           *(element_) [push_back(at_c<3>(qi::_val), qi::_1)] >>
                                                           "]"
                                                           );
    }
    private:
    rule<Iterator, composite_component()> start_rule_;
    element_parser<Iterator> element_;
};

template <typename Iterator>
class document_parser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, document(), qi::blank_type> {
public:
    document_parser() : document_parser::base_type{start_rule_}
    {

        using phoenix::at_c;
        using phoenix::push_back;
        using qi::_val;
        using qi::_0;
        using qi::_1;

        start_rule_ = +(element_)[push_back(at_c<0>(_val), _1)] >> qi::eoi;
    }
    private:
    rule<Iterator, document()> start_rule_;
    element_parser<Iterator> element_;
};

int main(int , char **) {
    document_parser<std::string::const_iterator> parser;
    document doc;
    const std::string text = "v 20180904 2\n"
                             "L 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n"
                             "C 10 10 FOO\n"
                             "[ "
                             "L 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n"
                             "]\n";
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(text.cbegin(), text.cend(), parser, qi::blank, doc);
    std::cout << (r ? "OK" : "FAIL") << std::endl;

     return 0;
}
```

Definitions of rules for 'text', 'circle' and 'box' are omitted, though. Note the comment in private section of `element_parser` definition - compiler will be unable to instantiate an incomplete class template `composite_element_parser<Iterator>`. What am I supposed to do with that? Obviously, I can't have `element_parser` and `composite_element_parser` as members of a top-level grammar (`document_parser` in my case) and pass them references/pointers to each other in the constructors initializer list, because they are uninitialized at the moment.

**UPDATE:** this thread may be likely recognized as a duplicate of  [Deeply-recursive qi grammars (parsers) with synthesized and inherited attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559965/deeply-recursive-qi-grammars-parsers-with-synthesized-and-inherited-attributes), but I really can't grasp the approved answer.

Comment: Are you sure you want `line_ || embedded_component_` instead of  `line_ | embedded_component_`? This part of the grammar is confusing me. Also, why is the element parser requiring `eoi`? That means you can never parse more than one.

Comment: @sehe, yes, the code is rather messy (your remarks are appreciated). But for the time I'm really more interested in approaching recursive grammars for my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56610770/85371) where I showed the approach passing references around, I simplified that answer to this:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct document_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, document()> {
    document_parser() : document_parser::base_type{start_}
    {
        using namespace qi;

        line_              = 'L' >> auto_;
        box_               = 'B' >> auto_;
        circle_            = 'S' >> auto_;
        // text            = 'T' >> ...;
        element_           = (line_ | box_ | circle_ | composite_element_) >> eol;
        elements_          = -skip(space) [ '[' >> skip(blank) [*element_] >> ']' ];
        composite_element_ = 'C' >> int_ >> int_ >> lexeme[+graph] >> elements_;

        document_          = +element_ >> eoi;

        start_ = skip(blank) [ document_ ];
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((document_)(element_)(composite_element_)(elements_)(line_));
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, document()> start_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, document(),             qi::blank_type> document_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, element(),              qi::blank_type> element_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, line(),                 qi::blank_type> line_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, box(),                  qi::blank_type> box_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, circle(),               qi::blank_type> circle_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, composite_component(),  qi::blank_type> composite_element_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<element>(), qi::blank_type> elements_;
};
```

Note that it parses boxes and circles too now. You may want to read about [Auto Parser](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auto.html) for that magic.

See it **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/g0OSNUDyVE7WN4Ud)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct line { int x1, y1, x2, y2, color, width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength, dashspace; };
struct box { int x, y, width, height, color, line_width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength, dashspace, filltype, fillwidth, angle1, pitch1, angle2, pitch2; };
struct circle { int x, y, radius, color, line_width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength; };
struct text { int x, y, color, size, visibility, show_name_value, angle, alignment, num_lines;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
};

struct composite_component;
using element_t = boost::variant<line, box, circle, text, boost::recursive_wrapper<composite_component>>;

struct element {
    // ...
    element_t element;
};

struct composite_component {
    int x;
    int y;
    std::string basename;
    std::vector<element> elements;
};

struct document { std::vector<element> elements; };

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(line, x1, y1, x2, y2, color, width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength, dashspace)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(box, x, y, width, height, color, line_width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength, dashspace, filltype, fillwidth, angle1, pitch1, angle2, pitch2)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(circle, x, y, radius, color, line_width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(text, x, y, color, size, visibility, show_name_value, angle, alignment, num_lines, lines)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(composite_component, x, y, basename, elements)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(element, element)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(document, elements)

template <typename Iterator>
struct document_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, document()> {
    document_parser() : document_parser::base_type{start_}
    {
        using namespace qi;

        line_              = 'L' >> auto_;
        box_               = 'B' >> auto_;
        circle_            = 'S' >> auto_;
        // text            = 'T' >> ...;
        element_           = (line_ | box_ | circle_ | composite_element_) >> eol;
        elements_          = -skip(space) [ '[' >> skip(blank) [*element_] >> ']' ];
        composite_element_ = 'C' >> int_ >> int_ >> lexeme[+graph] >> elements_;

        document_          = +element_ >> eoi;

        start_ = skip(blank) [ document_ ];
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((document_)(element_)(composite_element_)(elements_)(line_)(box_)(circle_));
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, document()> start_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, document(),             qi::blank_type> document_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, element(),              qi::blank_type> element_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, line(),                 qi::blank_type> line_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, box(),                  qi::blank_type> box_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, circle(),               qi::blank_type> circle_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, composite_component(),  qi::blank_type> composite_element_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<element>(), qi::blank_type> elements_;
};

int main(int , char **) {
    document_parser<std::string::const_iterator> parser;

    const std::string text = // "v 20180904 2\n"
         "L 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n"
         "C 10 10 FOO\n"
         "[ "
         "    L 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100\n"
         "]\n";

    document doc;
    bool r = qi::parse(text.cbegin(), text.cend(), parser, doc);
    std::cout << (r ? "OK" : "FAIL") << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
OK
```

And debug output:

```xml
<document_>
  <try>L 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 </try>
  <element_>
    <try>L 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 </try>
    <line_>
      <try>L 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 </try>
      <success>\nC 10 10 FOO\n[     L</success>
      <attributes>[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]</attributes>
    </line_>
    <success>C 10 10 FOO\n[     L </success>
    <attributes>[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]]</attributes>
  </element_>
  <element_>
    <try>C 10 10 FOO\n[     L </try>
    <line_>
      <try>C 10 10 FOO\n[     L </try>
      <fail/>
    </line_>
    <box_>
      <try>C 10 10 FOO\n[     L </try>
      <fail/>
    </box_>
    <circle_>
      <try>C 10 10 FOO\n[     L </try>
      <fail/>
    </circle_>
    <composite_element_>
      <try>C 10 10 FOO\n[     L </try>
      <elements_>
        <try>\n[     L 10 20 30 40</try>
        <element_>
          <try>     L 10 20 30 40 5</try>
          <line_>
            <try>     L 10 20 30 40 5</try>
            <success>\n]\n</success>
            <attributes>[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]</attributes>
          </line_>
          <success>]\n</success>
          <attributes>[[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]]</attributes>
        </element_>
        <element_>
          <try>]\n</try>
          <line_>
            <try>]\n</try>
            <fail/>
          </line_>
          <box_>
            <try>]\n</try>
            <fail/>
          </box_>
          <circle_>
            <try>]\n</try>
            <fail/>
          </circle_>
          <composite_element_>
            <try>]\n</try>
            <fail/>
          </composite_element_>
          <fail/>
        </element_>
        <success>\n</success>
        <attributes>[[[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]]]</attributes>
      </elements_>
      <success>\n</success>
      <attributes>[[10, 10, [F, O, O], [[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]]]]</attributes>
    </composite_element_>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[10, 10, [F, O, O], [[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]]]]]</attributes>
  </element_>
  <element_>
    <try></try>
    <line_>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </line_>
    <box_>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </box_>
    <circle_>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </circle_>
    <composite_element_>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </composite_element_>
    <fail/>
  </element_>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]], [[10, 10, [F, O, O], [[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]]]]]]]</attributes>
</document_>
```

Comment: Thank you and others very much.

Answer (score 4):

Usually you just do not split grammar that way. But if you really want, there are multiple ways:

1. Create grammars separately and assign grammars to `rule` placeholder externally:

   ```
   #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

   namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

   template <typename Iterator>
   struct grammar1 : qi::grammar<Iterator, int()>
   {
       grammar1() : grammar1::base_type{start_}
       {
           start_ = '[' >> outer >> ']';
       }

       qi::rule<Iterator, int()> outer;

   private:
       qi::rule<Iterator, int()> start_;
   };

   template <typename Iterator>
   struct grammar2 : qi::grammar<Iterator, int()>
   {
       grammar2() : grammar2::base_type{start_}
       {
           start_ = outer | qi::int_;
       }

       qi::rule<Iterator, int()> outer;

   private:
       qi::rule<Iterator, int()> start_;
   };

   int main()
   {
       char const* s = "[[123]]", * e = s + std::strlen(s);
       grammar2<char const*> g2;
       grammar1<char const*> g1;
       g2.outer = g1;
       g1.outer = g2;
       int value = 0;
       if (qi::parse(s, e, g1, value))
           std::cout << value << '\n';
       else
           std::cout << "failed\n";
   }
   ```

   https://wandbox.org/permlink/QhA18pIZwVlQ2osi
2. Create one grammar in other dynamically and pass to it a reference of the former:

   ```
   #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

   namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

   template <typename Iterator>
   struct grammar2;

   template <typename Iterator>
   struct grammar1 : qi::grammar<Iterator, int()>
   {
       grammar1()
           : grammar1::base_type{start_}
       {
           outer_ = std::make_unique<grammar2<Iterator>>(start_);
           start_ = '[' >> *outer_ >> ']';  // NOTE: it is not a kleen star!
       }

   private:
       std::unique_ptr<grammar2<Iterator>> outer_;
       qi::rule<Iterator, int()> start_;
   };

   template <typename Iterator>
   struct grammar2 : qi::grammar<Iterator, int()>
   {
       explicit grammar2(qi::rule<Iterator, int()> const& outer)
           : grammar2::base_type{start_}
       {
           start_ = outer | qi::int_;
       }

   private:
       qi::rule<Iterator, int()> start_;
   };

   int main()
   {
       char const* s = "[[123]]", * e = s + std::strlen(s);
       grammar1<char const*> const g1;
       int value = 0;
       if (qi::parse(s, e, g1, value))
           std::cout << value << '\n';
       else
           std::cout << "failed\n";
   }
   ```

   https://wandbox.org/permlink/hJz3v1ApK8GCkquS

Comment: Oh hey it's a spirit appreciation party :)

Comment: Okay, you came up with the exact two options I describe. +1 from me. I spent some more time debugging the grammars as well. There was a lot to unpack.

Comment: Oh spotted late: You don't actually need to dynamically instantiate in order to pass a reference (see my example that does that but doesn't dynamically instantiate)

Answer (score 3):

I think in your example there's no need to use grammar instances.

Rules can refer to each other recursively/cyclically (because they refer to each other by reference). I would leverage this.

> *You **can** still separate out grammar classes (e.g. to separate the implementations into compilation units) but you just want to glue them together at a central spot where you have the instances that you can then mutually reference (in other words: classical ownership management: if none of the classes can own objects, have another entity own them both).*

Alternatively you can simply pass references to the complementary grammars in the constructors, and keep those instead of the grammar instances.

### DEMO

For expedience sake I did the second approach¹.

I changed a few things:

- fixed the type of `composite_element::elements` from `std::vector<element_t>` to `std::vector<element>`
- Fixed a few things surrounding white-space skipping:

  - the `'[' ... ']'` block parsing did not allow for the newline characters that your input shows (see `skip(qi::space)`)
  - the `eol` is only required after `line_`, but your input shows it after other elements
  - the element parser wrongly requires `eoi` - that causes parsing to stop after the first element (and fail if that's not EOI).
  - the skipper isn't end-user serviceable. My credo is to hide it from the caller unless you want the caller to actually be able to change the skipper
- Added convenience `start_rule_` that code the skipper as well as making sure the top-level rules per grammar show up usefully in the debug output (if everything is called `start_rule_`, there's little information left)
- Removed everything `phoenix` (see [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil/)):

  - This example:

    ```
    start_rule_ = +(element_)[push_back(at_c<0>(_val), _1)] >> qi::eoi;
    ```

    That's what automatic attribute propagation already does, so this is enough:

    ```
    start_rule_ = +elements_ >> qi::eoi;
    ```
  - This:

    ```
    qi::lexeme[(qi::char_)[at_c<2>(qi::_val) += qi::_1]]
    ```

    Had a number of issues: it lacks a repeat (it parses 1 char only), it does NOT specify what characters are accepted, sp if repeated will read until EOI. I suspect this is what you wanted:

    ```
    qi::lexeme[+qi::graph]
    ```

    See also [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)
- Changed `||` into `|` (see [Alternative Parser](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/alternative.html) vs [Sequential-Or Parser](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/sequential_or.html)).
- Maybe more but I forgot? Oh yeah, I commented the `v` line.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39813a6cf79aec9a)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct line { int x1, y1, x2, y2, color, width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength, dashspace; };
struct box { int x, y, width, height, color, line_width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength, dashspace, filltype, fillwidth, angle1, pitch1, angle2, pitch2; };
struct circle { int x, y, radius, color, line_width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength; };
struct text { int x, y, color, size, visibility, show_name_value, angle, alignment, num_lines;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
};

struct composite_component;
using element_t = boost::variant<line, box, circle, text, boost::recursive_wrapper<composite_component>>;

struct element {
    // ...
    element_t element;
};

struct composite_component {
    int x;
    int y;
    std::string basename;
    std::vector<element> elements;
};

struct document { std::vector<element> elements; };

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(line, x1, y1, x2, y2, color, width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength, dashspace)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(box, x, y, width, height, color, line_width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength, dashspace, filltype, fillwidth, angle1, pitch1, angle2, pitch2)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(circle, x, y, radius, color, line_width, capstyle, dashstyle, dashlength)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(text, x, y, color, size, visibility, show_name_value, angle, alignment, num_lines, lines)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(composite_component, x, y, basename, elements)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(element, element)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(document, elements)

template <typename Iterator, typename Attribute>
using blank_rule = qi::rule<Iterator, Attribute, qi::blank_type>;

template <typename Iterator>
struct composite_element_parser;

template <typename Iterator>
struct element_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, element()> {
    element_parser(): element_parser::base_type{start_rule_},
        embedded_component_(*this)
    {
        using qi::int_;

        /* other definitions except of the 'line' is omitted in sake of simplicity */
        line_ = 'L' >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >>
                    int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_;
        // box = ...
        // circle = ...
        // text = ...
        element_rule_ = (line_ | embedded_component_) >> qi::eol;
        start_rule_ = qi::skip(qi::blank) [ element_rule_ ];
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((element_rule_)(line_));
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, element()> start_rule_;
    blank_rule<Iterator, element()> element_rule_;
    blank_rule<Iterator, line()> line_;
    composite_element_parser<Iterator> embedded_component_;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct composite_element_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, composite_component()> {
    composite_element_parser(element_parser<Iterator> const& ep)
        : composite_element_parser::base_type{start_rule_},
          element_(ep)
    {
        using qi::int_;
        elements_ = -qi::skip(qi::space) [ '[' >> *element_ >> ']' ];
        composite_element_rule_ = 'C' >> int_ >> int_ >> qi::lexeme[+qi::graph] >> elements_;
        start_rule_ = qi::skip(qi::blank) [ composite_element_rule_ ];
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((composite_element_rule_)(elements_));
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, composite_component()> start_rule_;
    blank_rule<Iterator, composite_component()> composite_element_rule_;
    blank_rule<Iterator, std::vector<element>()> elements_;
    element_parser<Iterator> const& element_;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct document_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, document()> {
    document_parser() : document_parser::base_type{start_rule_}
    {
        document_rule_ = +element_ >> qi::eoi;
        start_rule_ = qi::skip(qi::blank) [ document_rule_ ];
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((document_rule_));
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, document()> start_rule_;
    blank_rule<Iterator, document()> document_rule_;
    element_parser<Iterator> element_;
};

int main(int , char **) {
    document_parser<std::string::const_iterator> parser;

    const std::string text = // "v 20180904 2\n"
         "L 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n"
         "C 10 10 FOO\n"
         "[ "
         "    L 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100\n"
         "]\n";

    document doc;
    bool r = qi::parse(text.cbegin(), text.cend(), parser, doc);
    std::cout << (r ? "OK" : "FAIL") << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
OK
```

And the debug output:

```xml
<document_rule_>
  <try>L 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 </try>
  <element_rule_>
    <try>L 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 </try>
    <line_>
      <try>L 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 </try>
      <success>\nC 10 10 FOO\n[     L</success>
      <attributes>[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]</attributes>
    </line_>
    <success>C 10 10 FOO\n[     L </success>
    <attributes>[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]]</attributes>
  </element_rule_>
  <element_rule_>
    <try>C 10 10 FOO\n[     L </try>
    <line_>
      <try>C 10 10 FOO\n[     L </try>
      <fail/>
    </line_>
    <composite_element_rule_>
      <try>C 10 10 FOO\n[     L </try>
      <elements_>
        <try>\n[     L 10 20 30 40</try>
        <element_rule_>
          <try>L 10 20 30 40 50 60 </try>
          <line_>
            <try>L 10 20 30 40 50 60 </try>
            <success>\n]\n</success>
            <attributes>[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]</attributes>
          </line_>
          <success>]\n</success>
          <attributes>[[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]]</attributes>
        </element_rule_>
        <element_rule_>
          <try>]\n</try>
          <line_>
            <try>]\n</try>
            <fail/>
          </line_>
          <composite_element_rule_>
            <try>]\n</try>
            <fail/>
          </composite_element_rule_>
          <fail/>
        </element_rule_>
        <success>\n</success>
        <attributes>[[[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]]]</attributes>
      </elements_>
      <success>\n</success>
      <attributes>[[10, 10, [F, O, O], [[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]]]]</attributes>
    </composite_element_rule_>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[10, 10, [F, O, O], [[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]]]]]</attributes>
  </element_rule_>
  <element_rule_>
    <try></try>
    <line_>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </line_>
    <composite_element_rule_>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </composite_element_rule_>
    <fail/>
  </element_rule_>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]], [[10, 10, [F, O, O], [[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]]]]]]]</attributes>
</document_rule_>
```

---

¹ I don't usually do this, as it invites life time issues and I consider reference members a code smell unless for short-lived functor objects

Comment: Added the much simpler rule-approach here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56610971/85371 /cc @RadosławCybulski